# Can't make webpack ProvidePlugin work

Tags: plugins, webpack

I have file where I export object

```
let myHelper = {
  hello() {
   console.log('hello')
  }
}
export default myHelper;
```

In webpack I could set alias, and this work for e.g. `import myHelper from 'myHelper'`:

```
alias: {
  myHelper: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/folder/myHelper.js')
}
```

But I can't require it properly in ProvidePlugin. I've tried many possible combinations from other answers...

```
myHelper: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/folder/myHelper.js')
```

or

```
myHelper: ['app/folder/myHelper.js', 'default']
```

Webpack doesn't throw 'cannot find module' on start. but I've got 'myHelper' is undefined when trying to use it. What could be wrong?
I thought I could require it on ProvidePlugin and than just use without require anywhere else.

Comment: It should not be `export default myHelper` instead of `export default myObj` ?

Comment: @bonheury just a typo in description